# Repairing fiberglass garage door panel with large hole

Tags: repair, fiberglass, hole-repair

[image: large hole in corrugated fiberglass panel]

This large hole came with the garage when we bought the house. I would like to repair this to make it look a lot better, and at least keep prowling cats out. The backing you see in the picture behind the hole is just a floor tile I have propped up against it. I'm asking for repair steps rather than suggestions to replace the entire panel. It is important to me to match the corrugations with a repair and make it look like a decent repair, not a new panel.

[image: width of hole]

The hole's dimensions are roughly 11" x 11".

Comment: I don't see the pictures I added, only descriptions and links. What did I do wrong,  and how can I fix my question to make it more accessible to the eye?

Comment: @Aloysius Defenestrate, thanks! That looks a lot better.

Comment: That panel really needs to be replaced , look for the MFG name and see if you can still get that pattern then paint the entire door the fiberglass looks to be badly weathered and paint may extend the life but a hole that big on a panel in that rough shape will be visible after painting. I know you don’t want to hear to replace but you will spend more in time and effort and end up with a visible repair that probably won’t last.

Comment: you could make a patch by applying thin plastic sheet on a 15x15 area on back side of door to prevent fiberglass patch from sticking to the door .... create a fiberglass patch on the plastic sheet .... peel off the fiberglass patch  when set, and place over the hole from the back ... even out the hole from the front

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find a good section of door with the same pattern.

Spray release chemical on that section of door.  Build a box/frame with a back around this area.

Fill the box with expanding foam, so it extrudes against the door area.

Release the foam and box from the door.   You now have a mold.

Paint the mold with just enough epoxy to give it a hard shell (harder than normal foam).

Spray the foam and box with release agent.

Move this foam and box over to the damaged area and  attach it to the door.

Now you have a mold to do a fiberglas layup in the normal way.

Comment: would it be better to create the mold from the back side or front, in this case? I haven't actually done any fiberglassing before but have been wanting to try it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try to mimic the corrugations with thin strips of wood attached behind, then do a standard fiberglass cloth layup. (Unless you can get really lucky and find a matching corrugation to simply place over the hole.)